# Increase the width of white space in Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

You can see it is my new installed Sublime Text 3. The width of white space is a lot smaller than that of a character, and the width of white space doesn't change if increase the font-size.

**How should I set the width of white space?** It is not about "tab to space" at all.

[image]

Comment: Use a monospaced font. Whatever font you changed to is not monospaced and should not be used for programming.

Comment: Can you give me an example of nonospaced font? I don't know which one is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can. What font are you using?

Normally you would want to use a monospace typeface. Here are some of my favourites:

```
Source Code Pro
Deja Vu Sans Mono
Inconsolata
Hack
Droid Sans Mono
```

Comment: I am using Arial ( "font_face": "Arial",)

Comment: I searched and downloaded "Source Code Pro". Problem solved. Thanks!